# Precompiling scss files for css shim

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, shim

I'm trying to use an html shim to include IE specific stylesheets. However, keep running into a "ActionView::Template::Error (ie/IE9.css isn't precompiled):" error once deployed to heroku. It seems to work locally though.

I've been trying different combinations and locations for the assets but nothing has worked so far.

My current config is below.

The IE specific files are located in:

```
app/assets/stylesheets/ie/index.css.scss
app/assets/stylesheets/ie/IE9.css.scss
app/assets/stylesheets/ie/IE8.css.scss
app/assets/stylesheets/ie/IE7.css.scss
app/assets/stylesheets/ie/IE6.css.scss
```

index.css.scss

```
/*
*= require_tree .
*/
```

application.html.haml

```
/[if gte IE 9]
  = stylesheet_link_tag "ie/IE9", media: "all"
```

application.css.scss

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
 * or vendor/assets/stylesheets of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the top of the
 * compiled file, but it's generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *
 *= require bootstrap
 *= require baseline
 *= require base10creations/gallery_required
 *= require ie
 *= require_self

*/

@import 'baseline.css.scss';
@import 'rem.css.scss';
@import 'common.css.scss';
@import 'admin.css.scss';
@import 'layout.css.scss';
@import 'pages.css.scss';
@import 'components.css.scss';
@import 'forms.css.scss';
@import 'override.css.scss';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up getting just using a link tag instead of the rails stylesheet_link_tag. Though I have no idea why the stylesheet_link_tag was throwing a fit.

The working files are:

**directory structure**

```
app/assets/stylesheets/ie/index.css.scss
app/assets/stylesheets/ie/IE9.css.scss
app/assets/stylesheets/ie/IE8.css.scss
app/assets/stylesheets/ie/IE7.css.scss
app/assets/stylesheets/ie/IE6.css.scss
```

**index.css.scss**

```
/*
*= require_tree .
*/
```

**application.html.haml**

```
!!!
%html
  %head
    %meta{:charset => "UTF-8"}/
    %title= "Title"
    = stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all"
    = javascript_include_tag "application"
    = csrf_meta_tags
    /[if lt IE 9]
      %script{ src: "http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js", type: "text/javascript" }
    /[if gte IE 9]
      %link{ href: "ie/IE9.css" }
  %body
    #container
      = render :partial => "layouts/header"
      #content
        #messages
          - flash.each do |name, msg|
            = content_tag :div, msg, :id => "flash_#{name}"
        = yield
      = render :partial => "layouts/footer"
```

**application.css.scss**

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
 * or vendor/assets/stylesheets of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the top of the
 * compiled file, but it's generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *
 *= require bootstrap
 *= require baseline
 *= require base10creations/gallery_required
 *= require ie
 *= require_self

*/

@import 'baseline.css.scss';
@import 'rem.css.scss';
@import 'common.css.scss';
@import 'admin.css.scss';
@import 'layout.css.scss';
@import 'pages.css.scss';
@import 'components.css.scss';
@import 'forms.css.scss';
@import 'override.css.scss';
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of options in your case:

- in your `application.css` add :

  *= require_tree .
- use [index file technique](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#asset-organization) , which simply requires a new 'index' file in your `ie/` directory with the same content (`*= require_tree .`);

I would suggest to remove

```
config.assets.precompile += ["IE9.css", "IE8.css", "IE7.css", "IE6.css"]
```

from your `production.rb`  and your conditional call to IE shims in tour layout file `application.html.haml`.

EDIT: a better js for IE:

```
  /[if lt IE 9]
    <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Following this I added a blank index.css.scss file to the "ie" folder and remove the config.assets.precompile from my production.rb file. Per the link, in application.css.scss I added "*= require ie". It works locally but still fails with the same error when deployed to heroku.

Comment: Can you post your `application.css.scss`? Notice , that the index file should contain `*= require_tree .` routine.

Comment: I've changed the above to reflect the current setup.

Comment: I would suggest to place `*= require_self` on top of the requires and just to add `*= require_tree .` at the bottom.

Comment: I've added "*= require_tree ." to ie/index.css.scss but it still fails with the same error.

Comment: Have you removed `= stylesheet_link_tag "ie/IE9", media: "all"` from your `application.html.haml`?

Comment: I have not. How do I call the shim if not with a stylesheet_link_tag? just use %link?

Comment: If I use "*= require_tree ." instead of "*= require_self" I get the following error when trying to push to heroku: Undefined variable: "$maroon". (in /tmp/build_pa6rrk111st7/app/assets/stylesheets/admin.css.scss) The $maroon var is a mixin from the admin.css.scss stylesheet.

Comment: You should include them both, not one instead another. _self at the top, _tree . at the bottom.

Comment: By including "*= require_self" at the top and "*= require_tree ." at the bottom I still get the above error when pushing to heroku.

Comment: I can see you have not removed `= stylesheet_link_tag "ie/IE9", media: "all"` from your application.html.haml. It is going to be included by the manifest file `application.css.scss`, do try it. I think that's the problem. Also see my edited answer about IE js .

Comment: I understand what you're saying about IE.js which I am including, however in this situation I'm trying to include browser specific css overrides hence the shim. If I remove = stylesheet_link_tag "ie/IE9", media: "all" then the override will be included for all browsers.